# Extract only quarter from a date in r

Tags: r, date

I would like to extract ONLY the quarter from a date, e.g., to get an integer 1 from the date "2003-02-08". I have been trying something along this line

```
library(mondate)
as.yearqtr(dat$DATE)
```

> "2003 Q1"

```
as.character(as.yearqtr(dat$DATE))[1]
```

> "2003 Q1"

which hasn't been giving my desired result. Of course I can write conditions as follows

```
library(data.table)
data$DATE = as.Date(data$DATE, format='%d%b%Y')
data$month=month(data$DATE)
setDT(data)[month==1,  quarter:=1]  
    ...
```

This will work, but is not elegant at all. Is there a more beautiful way of doing this?

Thank you lmo and user2100721! I really wish I could accept all of the answers!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would do:

```
# example data
DT = data.table(id = 1:10, d = as.IDate("2003-02-08") + seq(100, by=50, length.out=10))

DT[, qtr := quarter(d)]

    id          d qtr
 1:  1 2003-05-19   2
 2:  2 2003-07-08   3
 3:  3 2003-08-27   3
 4:  4 2003-10-16   4
 5:  5 2003-12-05   4
 6:  6 2004-01-24   1
 7:  7 2004-03-14   1
 8:  8 2004-05-03   2
 9:  9 2004-06-22   2
10: 10 2004-08-11   3
```

The `quarter` function is provided by data.table and works on both `Date` and `IDate` vectors. (`IDate` uses integer storage.)

Answer (score 27):

There is a base R function, `quarters`, that more or less accomplishes what you want, though it prepends "Q". So

```
quarters(as.Date("2001-05-01"))
[1] "Q2"
```

If it is important to get rid of the "Q", you could use `substr`

```
substr(quarters(as.Date("2001-05-01")), 2, 2)
[1] "2"
```

Other date-related base R functions, such as `weekdays` and `months` can be found in help page `?quarters`.

Answer (score 8):

`lubridate` package has the same function. We can use that also. I am using @Frank's `DT`

```
DT[, qtr := lubridate::quarter(d)]
```

Answer (score 2):

`dint` package also is suitable for that:

```
library("dint")
d=as.Date("2015-01-01")
get_quarter(d)
```

you can find more about this package [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dint/vignettes/dint.html).