# Date to quarter without the year in r

Tags: r

I have a date format which i would like to be returned as a quarter without the year. So far I just found the way "year/quarter".

Can somebody help me?
Thanks a lot

Comment: `lubridate::quarter(your_date)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract only quarter from a date in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39209763/extract-only-quarter-from-a-date-in-r)