# Create a new data table with mean of specific column by quarters

Tags: r, data.table

I have a very long data table in the following format, where this here is just small a subset of the data table:

```
dt.data <- structure(list(delivDate = structure(c(20489, 20500, 20516, 20517, 
20518, 20533, 20541, 20546, 20549, 20559, 20564, 20573, 20579, 
20582, 20600), class = "Date"), priceDate = structure(c(19724, 
19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 
19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 19724), class = "Date"), priceIndex = c("HPFC DE", 
"HPFC DE", "HPFC DE", "HPFC DE", "HPFC DE", 
"HPFC DE", "HPFC DE", "HPFC DE", "HPFC DE", 
"HPFC DE", "HPFC DE", "HPFC DE", "HPFC DE", 
"HPFC DE", "HPFC DE"), avgPrice = c(109.65, 104.35, 
104.5, 103.91, 100.38, 76.57, 66.72, 83.24, 47.7, 87.17, 86.65, 
84.24, 83.68, 65.95, 83.73), quarters = c("Q1", "Q1", "Q1", "Q1", 
"Q1", "Q1", "Q1", "Q2", "Q2", "Q2", "Q2", "Q2", "Q2", "Q2", "Q2"
)), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
))
```

Now, I want to create a new data table `dt.meanPrice`, where the `avgPrice`-column represents the mean of the prices per `quarters`, where the quarters are refered to the `delivDate`-column.
So, for each `priceDate` I want to get the average price per delivDate-`quarters`.

Comment: OK? Why are you telling us about this very simple task? What is your question (and it shouldn't be "Please do this for me")?

Comment: [Extract quarters from date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39209763/extract-only-quarter-from-a-date-in-r) and then [take average for each quarter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21982987/mean-per-group-in-a-data-frame)

Comment: No it doesn't answer my question!